# Replace die statement

Tags: php, die

Currently my code looks like this

```
<?php
if($controlSomething) {
    include(header);
    echo "something";
    include(footer);
    die();
}

if($anotherControl) {
    include(header);
    doSomeOperations(); // would throw an error if $controlSometing is true
    echo "something else";
    include(footer);
    die();
}
?>
```

Clearly this is not a good way to do things. I want to move to something cleaner.

I created a view class to wrap the page and avoid the include(header)/include(footer) repetition. I also converted all the conditional statement, changing `if($condition)` into `function condition ()`.

Now what should I do ? I was thinking of something like this :

```
if(condition1()) { message for condition1 ...}
else if(condition2()) {}
```

The problem is that this file might be included by another file that will be executed because there is no die statement anymore.

So should I include a var like "Die" in the view object and check its value before doing anything on every page ? This doesn't seem clean to me.
I have thousands of lines of code like this so the more simple/automated the solution, the better.

Comment: Why is it "clearly not a good way to do things"?

Comment: Use functions with `return`s

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Because It does not help in separating the controler/view/model as I would like to (to create an API)

Comment: I get where the other people are coming from, but I think you'd do well to take a step back and re-think the basic architecture of this site. Are the two if conditions functionally separate views (rendering distinct data)? Are the if-statements you're writing meant as a controller which executes before running the view, or are they more like a 'router', which determines which controller to call based on the request? If this 'might be included by another file', my hunch is that this is a controller. ilovecode may end with a :P, but `exit()` makes your intention much more clear.